# Display a portlet in ligthbox in websphere 8

Tags: websphere-portal

Does somebody know how to display a portlet in a ligthbox or Dialogbox, like the next image:

*!failed to load image!*

I'm using `websphere portal 8`.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a whole portlet on it's own? Can the Dialog be part of another portlet?

If it has to be it's own portlet, I would suggest looking at creating a custom skin. The skin would wrap the portlet in dialog box using whatever your preferred JS library is. Then you should be able to invoke the dialog's "show" method to display the portlet in the dialog box.

Here is the basic documentation from IBM on creating a [custom skin](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+WebSphere+Portal+8+Product+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Creating_skins_wp8&content=pdcontent)